# Getting file full path when uploading file in html in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the full file path when uploading a file.

.
If we use safari or IE browser i am getting full file path but in firefox it is not working

how can i get the full file path name by using javascript or jquery in firefox.

Thanks

Comment: It's not possible for security reasons.

Answer (score 3):

You cant, for security reasons. the broswer knows nothing about the user's hard drive.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually for example if you want to load an image with full path you can use a code like:

```
<html>
<body>
<img src = "file:///C:/Users/UserName/Folder1/Folder2/image.jpeg" />
</body>
</html>
```

So in a program you could ask the user to copy-paste the full path in a textbox and you can add the "file:///" after to read the file from the browser.
If you drag and drop a file to the browser you will see how the browser reads its path.

This answer is useful for someone who wants to make an offline application running on browsers client side only. This example was tested in Firefox and not sure if this is valid anymore.

Comment: I upvoted your post because I have found it useful: it had never occurred to me that 1) a file can be directly dropped into the browser window; 2) the full path of the file then, logically, displays in the URL field.

Comment: @BriceC. Glad I helped. I cannot understand the downvotes. What I state is not wrong. Wheather is a bad practice or not is a criterion for downvoting

Comment: This comment can be very useful for the OP goal. I was searching for something similiar and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine why anyone would want this kind of feature in the first place. You are uploading files, not specifying your hard disk structure. If this is for a legitimate reason, simply show a text box next to the uploader asking for the local path.

Comment: Actually many users want this feature because they want to display the preview of going-to-upload file, perfect example of this preview is modern multiple file uploaders with image preview!

Comment: @Adnan previewing an image is not related to give file path to a website. There is a reason why no browser does this...