# Javascript: Use an object, instead of path to it for specific function

Tags: javascript, json, excel, object, path

I'm using the `excel-as-json` module (https://github.com/stevetarver/excel-as-json) and I have set it up so that it translates my `.xlsx` files to `.json`, but I now changed it so that the `.xlsx` is uploaded by the user in the front-end of the app.

I would like to run the convert on the uploaded Excel file, but since I am getting the user to upload it - I don't actually have a path to it, only the file object itself. So `excel-as-json` tells me that it cannot find the `src` file `[Object object]`

The excel as json function call is:

`convertExcel(src, dst, options, callback);`

What is the best way to pass the object as `src`? What if I store the `.xlsx` in my mongoDB, could I pass in its path easier then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not solution, but workaround: Get user to copy in path to file and use this. Based on answer from: [Getting file full path when uploading file in html in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9463368/getting-file-full-path-when-uploading-file-in-html-in-firefox)

**Note** this workaround only works for localhost

**Solution** I solved my issue by using a different module - sheet.js. I get the user to upload their file using an `<input>` tag and then use sheet.js to parse it into json, before sending it to the server where it will be stored.