# Unable to get full path of file dropped in browser due to security reasons. What to do?

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-applications, filepath

I'm developing a web-application with Django, which should manage and process a huge amount of user' files in local intranet. As the Django app and user files will host in the same local network, there is no necessity to upload files, it's ok to provide Django with full network path to the file via user's view.

I realised that it's [impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9463368/getting-file-full-path-when-uploading-file-in-html-in-firefox) to get full file path from the browser due to [security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1635329/how-to-get-full-path-from-fileupload-using-javascript) reasons.

There is a **lot** of files a user will process every day (around 150-200), so it's not ok to ask user to manually copy-paste full file path into the app. Initial design approach supposed user to drag-n-drop files from Windows Explorer to dedicated areas in the browser.

What's my options, community?

1. rewrite all front-end as Electron app (yikes! Just [because of it!](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/file-object.md)) and use Django only as REST API backend;
2. rewrite ducking everything as desktop app and lose all advantages Django provides (authorization, authentication, ORM, admin panel, gosh -- lots of it);
3. the third funny option

I feel a little stranded. Need some advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered same problem while working on [this](https://github.com/ByK95/bookmark).

When I think on your options

1- There is no need to re-write whole app

- Create an api endpoint on server side
- Create a script(program) on client that will push real paths to server

  > Your files should be accessible over network

Here is the script code that I used:
Tested with python Python 3.7.4 Prints realpath of all the selected files as a list. 
 [source](https://github.com/ByK95/bookmark/blob/master/bookmark.py#L43)

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import pathlib

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

root.attributes("-topmost", True)
file_path = filedialog.askopenfilenames()
# print(file_path) #debug
files = list(file_path)
print(files)
```

Then you need to import either a `requests` and generate a Json request to your server endpoint.Or just call a `curl` with `subprocess`.

2- By your definition I assume the intranet network is trusted.So is authentication necessary.And there is a question of How many users will use same file after it is processed in server.If its one then there is no need for a django app.

Comment: Thanks for input, Bayram.

Unfortunately, use small local GUI app to push the full paths to the web-app isn't an option. It looks really cumbersome: first, user have to push them to the web-app; second, user have to do it's work in web-app (tick some checkboxes and radiobuttons) for every file. Practically it's easier for user to tick the boxes in the same GUI app.

And regarding Django app: the project is a multiuser system with various user roles and complex parallel file processing. Celery/RabbitMQ, Postgres, 3rd party APIs and all that stuff, so actually Django helps a lot :)

Comment: How about converting checkboxes and radiobuttons into RESTful service and creating a local GUI, or you can just create a wrapper around a local GUI app with WebView?

Comment: hmm, it looks like a mix of 1st and 2nd options. Will think about it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well...
I've solved my problem. With much less blood than expected, which I'm happy of. :)

First, I installed Electron and one of minimal boilerplates into a new folder in my project.

In boilerplate there is a file called `main.js` (or `index.js`, depends on boilerplate), which defines Electron application window and its contents. Inside is the line which loads content to Electron `BrowserWindow` object:

```js
mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
```

Fortunately, `BrowserWindow` object does have method `loadURL`, which can be used to load webpage **instead** of local html file:

```js
mainWindow.loadURL('http://127.0.0.1:8000');
```

It means that all pages rendered by Django will be shown in Electron browser, which runs node.js instead of standard browser javascript engine. Thus, this code in Django page template will work perfectly:

```html
<h1 id="holder">DROP FILES HERE</h1>
<p id="dropped"></p>

<script>
    const dropZone = document.getElementById('holder');

    dropZone.addEventListener('drop', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      let filesList = '\n';
      for (const f of e.dataTransfer.files) filesList += f.path + '\n';
      document.getElementById('dropped').innerHTML = `Full file paths: ${filesList}`;
    });

    dropZone.addEventListener('dragover', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Does using Electron mean that the application is now a desktop application? Or can you continue using it in the standard browser with the NodeJS engine?