# Override browser's "fakepath" security on file selection in intranet

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload

```html
<input type="file"
  onchange="this.nextElementSibling.textContent = this.value;">
<p>
```

I'm on intranet without any specific security demands. Only Chrome is available to users.

How can I force bypassing browser's security to allow real path, on browse button?

Already tried changing internet option on trusted website. not working.
I don't want to cut out the 'fakepath', and don't want to upload the file to the server. Just pass the path.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Why do you need to file path to begin with?

Comment: To better understand what the problem might be here, actually run the code and select a file. I get a text underneath the input element that starts with `C:\fakepath\...`. This happens on Firefox and Chrome. This must be related to the `onchange` event code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do browsers present selected files as coming from C:\fakepath\ instead of their true local path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851595/why-do-browsers-present-selected-files-as-coming-from-c-fakepath-instead-of-th)

Comment: @Reyno I need to pass the fullpath to the backend, and from there pass it to other systems. The location is common and secured.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I know there's a security prevention. As I wrote, I'm on intranet, and implementing client on a secured site.

Comment: The HTML file input is used for uploading files. It's purpose is not to send a real local path. If you want to pass a full local path you can use a HTML text input and copy the path into it.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware but I need a browse button. How can I achieved that without HTML file input?

Comment: Well, I did find [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59937110/unable-to-get-full-path-of-file-dropped-in-browser-due-to-security-reasons-what/59990858#59990858), but your users need to install something. I'm not sure you'll be happy with that. In general you cannot browse local files from the browser and get the full path because this would be a real security risk.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware thanks. It really solves some things. But users end allows only Chrome